# Why did Keith Mars refer to Veronica as Felicia?

Tags: character, dialogue, veronica-mars

In S04E01 "Spring Break Forever" of *Veronica Mars*, while Keith & Veronica are having their usual father-daughter banter, he call her out as "Bye Felicia".

> VERONICA: I'm gonna Irish exit this wingding. Tell the host it was lame as fuck.
>
> KEITH: Why are you sounding like that?
>
> VERONICA: The struggle is real. Hashtag JOMO.
>
> KEITH: Bye, Felicia.

What is this in reference to? Why did Keith call Veronica as Felicia?

[image: screenshots of scene with above dialogue]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Bye Felicia is a common meme.

Here's what it means.

> When someone says that they're leaving and you could really give two shits less that they are. Their name then becomes "felicia", a random bitch that nobody is sad to see go. They're real name becomes irrelevant because nobody cares what it really is. Instead, they now are "felicia".
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Urban Dictionary: bye felicia](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bye%20felicia)</sub>

A.K.A. it means begone!

It originates from the 1995 comedy film *Friday*, here's the dialogue.

> Felicia: Let me borrow a joint.
>   Smokey: You need to borrow a job with your broke ass. Always trying to smoke up somebody's shit. Get the hell on Felicia.
>   Felicia: I'm gonna remember that.
>   Smokey: Remember it. Write it down. Take a picture. I don't give a fuck!
>   Felicia: Craig?
>   Craig Jones: 'Bye, Felisha.
>   Felicia: Damn. Y'all stingy.

The meme started around 2008.

> On December 7th, 2008, Urban Dictionary user pimpin'817 submitted an entry for "bye felicia," describing the phrase as a way to bid farewell to someone who is deemed unimportant. On October 27th, 2011, YouTuber Mamclol uploaded a video titled "Bye Felicia," featuring the clip from Friday with an accompanying hip hop track about the character.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Bye Felicia - Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/bye-felicia)</sub>

If you want to go more into depth here is a <s>Thesis</s> history of the meme. [Bye Felicia - Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/bye-felicia)